# How to release channel after use in Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm new to Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to get a motor working by switching pins on and off. It's working fine however I'm getting these warnings when I try to setup the pins:

```
test2.py:17: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(pin1,GPIO.OUT)
test2.py:18: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(pin2,GPIO.OUT)
test2.py:19: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(pin3,GPIO.OUT)
```

It doesn't seem to cause any issue since the motor is still working, however I would like to get rid of them if possible.

I guess I need to somehow release the pin channel at the end of my program, but how can I do that?

For info this is my complete program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

pin1=17
pin2=18
pin3=27
pin4=22

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pin2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pin3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pin4,GPIO.OUT)

Apin1=[0,1,0,0,1]
Apin2=[0,1,1,0,0]
Apin3=[0,0,1,1,0]
Apin4=[0,0,0,1,1]
current=0
target=0

def GO_THERE(target,current):
    if current<target:
        while current<target:
            i=current&2 + 1
            GPIO.output(pin1,Apin1[i])
            GPIO.output(pin2,Apin2[i])
            GPIO.output(pin3,Apin3[i])
            GPIO.output(pin4,Apin4[i])
            time.sleep(.003)
            current= current + 1
    else:
        while current>target:
            i=current&2 + 1
            GPIO.output(pin1,Apin1[i])
            GPIO.output(pin2,Apin2[i])
            GPIO.output(pin3,Apin3[i])
            GPIO.output(pin4,Apin4[i])
            time.sleep(.003)
            current= current - 1
    print current,target
    return current;

target=4096
current=GO_THERE(target,current)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end of your program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  

# your init code 
try:  
    # your main loop

except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    #  handle ctrl-c

except:  
    #  other exceptions


finally:  
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

As mentioned on [RPi.GPIO basics 3 – How to Exit GPIO programs cleanly, avoid warnings and protect your Pi](http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-3-how-to-exit-gpio-programs-cleanly-avoid-warnings-and-protect-your-pi):

> RPi.GPIO provides a built-in function GPIO.cleanup() to clean up all
>   the ports you’ve used. But be very clear what this does. It only
>   affects any ports you have set in the current program. It resets any
>   ports you have used in this program back to input mode. This prevents
>   damage from, say, a situation where you have a port set HIGH as an
>   output and you accidentally connect it to GND (LOW), which would
>   short-circuit the port and possibly fry it. Inputs can handle either
>   0V (LOW) or 3.3V (HIGH), so it’s safer to leave ports as inputs.

And `GPIO.cleanup()` does not clean up all ports because:

> If it did clean up all the ports, this would mean you could have major
>   conflicts between different programs, which might not even be trying
>   to use the same ports. Clearly, not a desirable situation!

P.S.: There is a [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).